# Would you say "Let's head in!"?

Tags: meaning

Do we have such expression in English? (I don't remember where I saw it, but I'm sure I did)

> Let's head in!

Comment: Without context I don't see how this can mean anything. At least with *"Let's head **off**!"* we can assume the speaker means *"...off **away from here**"* even if we've no idea exactly *where*. But *"in"* requires at least some credible referent to make any kind of sense at all.

Comment: Does this not exist in British English? It's extremely common in the US. At the end of a long day at the beach someone might say "Do you want to swim some more?" "No, let's head in." Meaning, "Let's go home."

Comment: @Greg: That in itself is a specific context, where ***in*** can fairly obviously be seen as contrasting with the fact that we're currently ***out*** (on the beach, whatever). The same would apply to ***up/down*** if we were currently at an unusually low or high location, but I can't see much point in asking whether *Let's head up!* is an "expression" in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we use this all the time. Usually it means to go home, but as the other example showed, we sometimes use it to refer to going to some other destination. I think it has a nautical origin. The "heading" of a ship is the direction it is going.

Comment: I agree about the nautical origin. If you are in a boat, it can mean "Let's head in [toward shore]."

Answer (score 1):

This is fine.  It could be people on the beach wanting to head into the water or people outside a restaurant wanting to head into the restaurant.

Comment: I disagree, I've never heard "Let's go in"  to the water, it's almost always something like:

Comment: wait, how do you delete a comment?

Comment: Note:  It has to be “head into the water” because “head in the water” means to put your head under the surface of the water. The examples here only work if the destination is emphasized, otherwise “in” means home (for a boat that means the shore). The emphasis can be implied. For example, if you already know you will be going inside the restaurant.  Summary:  Take destination clues from the context.  If there is no context, then "in" means home or shore.